# jq - convert milliseconds

Tags: json, jq

input json:

```
{
  "id": "3885",
  "login": "050111",
  "lastLoginTime": 1529730115000,
  "lastLoginFrom": "192.168.66.230"
}
{
  "id": "3898",
  "login": "050112",
  "lastLoginTime": null,
  "lastLoginFrom": null
}
```

filter works when lastlogintime exists:

```
$ jq -jr --arg ARG1 050111 'select(.login==$ARG1)|"user:", " ",.login,"\n","lastlogintime:", " ",(.lastLoginTime / 1000 | strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M UTC")),"\n","lastloginfrom:", " ",.lastLoginFrom // "-","\n"' test_json3
user: 050111
lastlogintime: 2018-06-23 05:01 UTC
lastloginfrom: 192.168.66.230
```

but there is problem (does not print "-") when lastlogintime does not exist:

```
$ jq -jr --arg ARG1 050112 'select(.login==$ARG1)|"user:", " ",.login,"\n","lastlogintime:", " ",(.lastLoginTime / 1000 | strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M UTC")),"\n","lastloginfrom:", " ",.lastLoginFrom // "-","\n"' test_json3
user: 050112
jq: error (at test_json3:12): null (null) and number (1000) cannot be divided
```

how to skip divide operation for empty lastlogintimes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jq -r --arg ARG1 050112 'select(.login == $ARG1)|
    ["user:", .login],
    ["lastlogintime:", if .lastLoginTime then (.lastLoginTime/1000 | strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M UTC")) else "-" end],
    ["lastloginfrom:", .lastLoginFrom // "-"]
    |@tsv' file.json
```

That is, use an explicit `if`-`then`-`else` for when `lastLoginTime` is defined or not.